# Application logs not getting updated

Tags: java

Am facing similar issue in my application.
Updated with new log4j properties.

## Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=tmp\applicatione2e.log                              
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Whereas after running the application , not able to find the updated log file in the given path. Can anyone help me how to fix it?`

Comment: `tmp\applicatione2e.log` is a relative path. What's it relative to? What's the absolute path?

Comment: Try using a / (slash) instead of a \ (backslash) as path separator. In property files backslash is an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=tmp\applicatione2e.log

log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB

log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Comment: Also please check the proper file permission